# Regex Expression - Cannot Drop The @ Sign

Tags: regex, barcode

Hello guys having some regex issues. I am trying to parse a barcode that has the following format: `#D0208#@01^`   I need to be able to get the data after the @ and before the ^. My regex was working fine until I put a single piece of data in between the indicators such as `#D0208#@1^` or `#D0208#@A^` then everything fell apart and the @ sign was becoming troublesome. This is the regex code i'm currently working with: `\w{0,}[^#D0208#\@\^\r]` any ideas or regex gurus out there would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your regex uses a character class for grouping?

Comment: Add a language tag and show an example successful match and unsuccessful match in that language.

Comment: maybe you should use something like this: `\@(.*)\^` and then get the first group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take advantage of using character classes like this:

```
[^@]+@([^^]+)\^
```

That will match up to and including an `@`, then capture non `^` up to just before `^`

So if in English you are trying to capture what is between `@` and `^` this will do the trick.

You can play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/JPYMmJ/1

Answer (score 0):

```
.*@.*\^
```

This regex assumes that

1. There is one `@` in your string
2. The `^` is at the end
3. The whole input is the barcode
4. The signs between and before can be anything, including `@` and `^`

If you got a whitespace or something always in front of your barcode, simply add a `\b` (word boundary) or a `(?< )` (positive lookahead for a space) at the front

This regex doesnt match if the expression does

1. Not Contain a `@` OR
2. Not end with a `^`

i.e. `@^` would match as well